# Why am I getting this error in Nodejs? Error: Couldn't resolve host name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, insomnia

While testing registration API by Insomnia I am getting this error in insomnia preview: **Couldn't resolve host name**. I am using mongodb database which had been connected with my application.
[Image of Insomnia error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8Rc.png)

Why am I getting this error while everything seems okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your POST URL. You have typed `http//:` two times.

Comment: Thanks, Now I am getting a new Error: could not connect to server. Eventhough in the log i am getting connected to database message.